# What are the basic requirements of an API or a client-server system to be considered as RESTFul?

Tags: rest, web, httprequest

I'm having trouble to find exactly the core concepts or basic requirements to call an API or a system RESTful, what are the most basic core points  needed to be fulfilled in order to make a system considered as RESTFul?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer -- is that what you've been looking for? ))

Comment: Fielding explained that a RESTful API [must be hypertext-driven](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) to start with. He further explained the implications the constraints he put onto REST lead to and what will happen when you not adhere to the constraints. In the end, the ultimate goal of REST is the decoupling of clients from servers which allows server to evolve freely. Clients on the other hand will adapt to changes better and wont break that easily, especially in comparison to traditional RPC based services (RMI, Corba, SOAP, ...)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble to find exactly the core concepts or basic requirements to call an API or a system RESTful, what are the most basic core points needed to be fulfilled in order to make a system considered as RESTFul?

Start by reading Dr Fielding's thesis.  Chapter 5 defines the [REST architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5), with the earlier chapters laying the essential ground work of each of the constraints.

But in summary: REST looks like the world wide web: standardized [identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), standardized [media types](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/), standardized [messaging protocols](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), generic [hypermedia](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) clients with caches.